# Anyone setup "wraith" visual comparison on centos?

Tags: testing

I am trying to run wraith script on centOS. Ruby installation get stuck with 2.3.0 version.

Appreciate if anyone has any steps?

thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Try to install ruby with rvm instead:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Afterwards:
Reload shell configuration & check

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Check …

```
ruby –v 
rvm –v
```

Start ruby

```
rvm ruby-2.x.x
```

As a working alternative you could use the prebuilt Wraith docker container:

```
docker pull bbcnews/wraith
```